# How add custom text under comment form

Tags: comments, forms

I am currently using "Advanced Comment Form" but I am saturated with plugins and I wanted to do it with code.
Can somebody help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the comment form. WordPress provides various hooks. See [comment_form()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comment_form/).

**Actions**

- comment_form_comments_closed
- comment_form_before
- comment_form_must_log_in_after
- comment_form_top
- comment_form_logged_in_after
- comment_form_before_fields
- comment_form_after_fields
- comment_form
- comment_form_after

**Filters**

- comment_form_default_fields
- the_permalink
- comment_form_defaults
- comment_form_logged_in
- comment_form_fields
- comment_form_field_comment
- comment_form_field_{$name}
- comment_form_submit_button
- comment_form_submit_field

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but I am a designer, not a programmer.